# Parse UI Not Found Error in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, parseui

I recently updated to Xcode 7 and am using the Parse framework in my app (Parse, Bolts, and ParseUI).  I have changed nothing, however when I open the app in Xcode 7 I'm presented with one error that says "ParseUI/ParseUI.h not found".

[image]

I've deleted Parse UI from link binary with libraries and re-added it to no avail. The error only displays for the #import `#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>` line only in one view controller (despite that I have the same import statement in multiple other view controllers).  I also tried adding it to the app delegate (as I saw something about this on another stackoverflow post but that doesn't help either), Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm at a loss.

[image]

Comment: Did you downloaded new SDK? because ParseUI is updated before 2 days.

Comment: @iAshish Yes, that's the latest SDK.

Comment: Ok, Then wait for the answer.

Comment: when you add parse framework that time select Add to targets or not?

Comment: @Rohitsuvagiya I only have one target. Where should I have added to all targets? Sorry, not following...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out my own problem.  Parse made ParseUI a separate cocoapod. I deleted all the parse frameworks I manually added and added the Parse and Parse UI pods. Ran a quick pod install, opened the workspace, cleaned the project, and ran it.  It built without errors.

Answer (score 1):

Just now encountered the same issue with a new project built in xcode 7 (latest as of today). What I did to solve was check the box 'Copy items if needed' when importing the Parse framworks. This allowed the project to build right-away and no more 'xxxxx not found' errors.

Hope this helps!